# Как работает streambuf?

Tags: c++

Странно, но на этот класс как-то мало описания в инете...

Может скинете ссылки или напишите здесь более подробное описание? )

Понимаю, сейчас заминусуют... Но вдруг, кто-нибудь скинет грамотную ссылку...

Comment: Странно, а как вы искали? [а здесь например, чем не устраивает?](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/streambuf/streambuf/?kw=streambuf)

Comment: Инглишь не понимаю)

Comment: Вообще, даже технический? [тогда здесь](http://ru.cppreference.com)

Comment: Спасибо, подошло... Ну конечно, читаю и по-английски... Видимо дело привычки...